# Angularjs ngResource

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, hibernate

I'm new to Angularjs and I've been looking for some examples, I've seen some questions related to mine but not of the solutions given has worked for me and I really need help so I hope someone give me a hand please.

I have a RESTApi in Java, a bean, a DAO and a Service class and I'm using Hibernate to communicate with the db that it's in MySQL.

***This is my bean:***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PERSON")
@XmlRootElement(name = "Person")
//@XmlType(propOrder = {"id", "fullName", "age"})
public class Person {

    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(Person.class);


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "FULL_NAME")
    private String fullName;
    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private int age;

    @XmlElement
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(" Id: " + this.id + " Name: " + this.fullName +  " Age: " + this.age + " ");

        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

***This method is to get all the records from the db and it's in my DAO:***

```
public List<Person> getAllPersons() {
    List<Person> persons = null;
    Session session = null;

    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        persons = session.createQuery("FROM Person").list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        LOGGER.info("Query Ok");

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (session != null) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    return persons;

}
```

***And this is my method for the service to get a list in JSON format.***

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/getAllPersonsInJSON")
public List<Person> getAllPersonsInJSON() {

    return  personDao.getAllPersons();
}
```

All this is my back end.

Now I was looking a tutorial in YouTube where you have to create a web project and use a custom template for angularjs, so in this tutorial there are three files that you have to modify, Services.js, Controller.js and partial1.html, here's my code for each file.

**Service:**

```
var personService = angular.module('myApp.services', [ 'ngResource' ]);

personService.factory('Person', function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8080/rest/person/getAllPersonsInJSON',
            {}, {
                findAll : {
                    method : 'GET',
                    isArray : true
                }

            })

});
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).controller('MyCtrl1',
        function($scope, Person) {
            $scope.allPersons = Person.findAll();
//          console.log("Data_: " + JSON.stringify(Person.findAll()));

        }).controller('MyCtrl2', [ '$scope', function($scope) {

} ]);
```

**Partial1:**

```
<h3>View 1</h3>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="persons in allPersons">Person</li>
</ul>
```

So in this html file it supposed to display a list with all the records on the db but is not, I'm using Chrome network tool and I'm getting 200 status that it's ok, but in console I'm getting this message:

***Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object***

So I'm stuck and I really need help and please someone tell me what am I doing wrong cause I've been dealing with this for two days!

Thank you for you help, time and attention.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Check what is returned from your service, it is probably a Persons object containing a list of Person rather than just a list of person. In that case, isArray should be false in your Service javascript.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time! 
Actually I did that before and the error is gone but when I refresh the browser I can only see one element on the list and it supposed to have 5 because it's the number of records that I have in  my db.

Comment: I also put the URL in the browser and I'm able to see all the records in JSON format.

Comment: @KennethEspinal Can you get the full json object retrieved stored  in allPersons (e.g., using alert) and post it here?

Comment: Sure, I did it like this "alert('All Persons: ' + $scope.allPersons);"

And I got this in the alert " All Persons: [object Object] "